# Lightweight music player

Tags: software-recommendation, music-player

Is there any ultra lightweight music player for Ubuntu (like foobar)?

Preferably with Unity taskbar integration.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/omg-5-five-lightweight-music-players/

Comment: I think that in order to know, we at least should compare how heavy is the process with the following command:

top -c -p $(pgrep -d',' -f musicPlayerName)  

to really now, and always test with an specific MP3 file.

Answer (score 13):

Audacious is integrated in Lubuntu by default, because of its light-weightedness. You can try it: `sudo apt-get install audacious`. It supports two different layouts: a GTK-interface, and a Winamp-like interface, from which the latter can be skinned. It doesn't support Unity Sound Menu integration.

[image: This is the GTK-interface.]

*Above: the GTK-interface*

[image: This is the Winamp-like interface]

*Above: the Winamp-like interface*

Answer (score 1):

Check out: http://www.xnoise-media-player.com/, you can get it on Ubuntu through:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shkn/xnoise
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xnoise xnoise-plugins
```

But no taskbar integration (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Try [qmmp [image: Install qmmp]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qmmp).

It's very similar to winamp and supports winamp skins. Right click on the interface, 'Settings' (Ctrl-P), 'Appearance' - Skins - Add.

[image]

or copy the .wsz files to ~/.qmmp/skins

[image]

Can handle multiple playlists - go to 'Settings' (Ctrl-P), 'Playlist' and check 'Show playlists'.

And it will look like so (example with a different skin):

[image]

It's in Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite Foobar2000 substitute is [gmusicbrowser](http://gmusicbrowser.org/): "An open-source jukebox for large collections of mp3/ogg/flac/mpc/ape files, written in perl."

I'm not sure how lightweight it is, but it has one feature which made me fall in love with FooBar2000: **multiple entries per tag!** That is, you can tag your duets with two artist names and have only "Artist A" and "Artist B" in you set of artist instead of also "Artist A feat. Artist B". The same goes for genres etc. Wonderful for large music collections! Highly recommended!

Answer (score 1):

Using Xubuntu for a while and fanatically searched for a player that would be light and also would have some essential (to me) capabilities like folder/file browsing and multiple/tabbed play lists. I think most out there are too weak or too bloated. Clementine seemed ok until I found Deadbeef.
Deadbeef beats them all.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexey-smirnov/deadbeef
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install deadbeef
```

Or download as .deb [here](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/download.html).

To have the file browser you must install a plugin. Plugins have the .so extension and you have to open the file explorer (e.g. thunar) in root (sudo thunar) and put these files in ~/.local/lib/deadbeef/ folder.

Comment: I think you could remove "It is said to be the future default player in Lubuntu."

Comment: @vasa1 - did that. have you more info on the matter?

Comment: No, but I haven't come across any chatter indicating the inclusion of this player in a future release. There's generally a discussion in the [mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/lubuntu-users) of any impending changes.

Comment: @vasa1 - about a year and a few months ago i was so new to ubuntu i misunderstood [an old post about ubuntu 10.10](http://lubuntu.net/tags/deadbeef)

Answer (score 0):

try quark you can find it [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/quark/). It's very light.

Answer (score 0):

foobar2000 is a freeware snap package that can be easily installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command.

```
sudo snap install foobar2000
```

#### Features

- Supported audio formats are MP3, MP4, AAC, CD Audio, WMA, Vorbis, Opus, FLAC, WavPack, WAV, AIFF, Musepack, Speex, AU, SND and more with additional components.
- Gapless playback
- Easily customizable user interface layout
- Advanced tagging capabilities
- Support for ripping Audio CDs as well as transcoding all supported audio formats using the Converter component
- Full ReplayGain support
- Customizable keyboard shortcuts
- Open component architecture allowing third-party developers to extend
  functionality of the player

f you need to have full access to external media (such as USB flash drive, SD/MicroSD card, additional mounted hard drive and so on), run the following command:

```
sudo snap connect foobar2000:removable-media
```