# What are the minimum system requirements for Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, system-requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which version and derivate of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minmal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware)

Will Lubuntu work well on a Dell Dimension 4100 with these specifications:

- CPU: Intel Pentium III
- Memory:   384M
- Hard Drive Capacity:  20G
- Processor Speed:  800MHz

Comment: CPU: 1Ghz Intel Pentium 3m
RAM: 128MB
HDD: 20GB
OS: Lubuntu 12.04
WORKS: Long install time, but works well once running.

Answer (score 20):

I know the System Requirements for the Desktop version show that it is recommended on PCs with more than 1GB of RAM. but I have to mention 2 cases for me:

**CPU**: 700Mhz Intel Pentium 3
**RAM**: 256MB
**HDD**: 20GB
**OS**: Lubuntu 12.04
**WORKS**: Like a Charm 2.0 ^^

**CPU**: 550Mhz Intel Pentium 3
**RAM**: 128MB
**HDD**: 40GB
**OS**: Lubuntu 12.04
**WORKS**: Like a Charm 2.0 ^^

In both cases I am using Lubuntu and test it, well everything. There was no lag, no problems, no nothing. Just works and it truly makes the PC come to life. I mean they had Windows XP and the minute they had Lubuntu and the users learned in a day how to use it they told me they felt the PCs as if they were brand new. They even booted faster.

Another case is a laptop I have here:

**BRAND**: Dell Latitude CPx Notebook
**CPU**: 650Mhz Pentium 3
**RAM**: 128MB
**HDD**: 6GB
**OS**: Lubuntu 12.04
**WORKS**: Like a duck in the water. Like an elephant in Africa. Like my teeth on a Pizza.

And the last case which I mention also here: [Lighter in CPU/Memory Usage: Lubuntu or Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112418/lighter-in-cpu-memory-usage-lubuntu-or-xubuntu) is this PC:

**CPU** - Pentium 2 450Mhz
**RAM** - 64MB DIMM
**HDD**: 20GB
**OS**: Lubuntu 12.04
WORKS: When pigs fly!. I have to actually put 128MB RAM total to install it, then I took the memory and left it again with 64MB. I can't say it runs smooth but it sure beats the speed of others. Takes a bit longer to start (About a minute) and to open anything but come on, that is 64MB. My pen drive is 32GB. I can't ask the PC for more.

This pretty much gives you an idea. For your PC I am sure it will work correctly and smooth. I am even more sure that it will work even better than Windows XP or higher.

Answer (score 6):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu

### System Requirements

> A Pentium II or Celeron system with 128 MB of RAM. Desktop CD should not be used to install on systems with less than 1 GB of RAM. Please download the alternate ISO.