# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS vs 12.04 LTS Performance comparison

Tags: 12.04

Can you tell me more about performance comparrison between 10.04 and 12.04. Is 12.04 much resource hungry?
I have Pentium 4 2.8 GHz, 1.5 GB of RAM and NVidia GeForce FX 5500. Is that enough for smooth Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ofcourse** there are various improvements from 10.04 you can see [General info here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/press-reaction-to-ubuntu-12-04-mostly-positive/) and through [here](http://all-things-linux.blogspot.in/2012/05/ubuntu-shootout-1004-lts-vs-1204-lts.html).

For requirements and also improvements refer the [Official Ubuntu System Requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop/#System_Requirements) and [here too](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/amd64/minimum-hardware-reqts.html).

**System requirements**

> While the minimum memory requirement for **32bit is 384 MB**, a
> minimum of 512 MB is needed for the 64bit installation. On systems
> with only the bare minimum amount of memory, it is also strongly
> recommended to use the "Install Ubuntu" option as it uses less memory
> than the full live session.
>
> The Ubuntu 12.04 installation image does not include support for old
> computers that do not support PAE. If your computer is affected, you
> can either first install Ubuntu 10.04 or 11.10 and upgrade to 12.04 or
> you can use the Lubuntu or Xubuntu images. The non-PAE version of the
> Linux kernel will be dropped completely following the12.04 release.

**Ubuntu 12.04** will run fine enough on your posted specifications.

You may also try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) , you can further read about Lubuntu’s requirements from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162626/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-lubuntu).