# Creating ubuntu 7.10 bootable usb?

Tags: usb, 7.10

I'm trying to make a bootable 7.10 usb but can't seem to find any software that supports older distributions of ubuntu. Is there anyway around this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want such an old version of Ubuntu? It is no longer updated with supported updates and has security issues. If you are having issues because it doesn't recognize your processor/CPU, then there is a workaround for even the newest version. If performance if your worry, there are ways to streamline.

Comment: `why` 7.10   and why not 12.04 would be first question , and using `dd` would be the answer :)

Comment: I just got my hands on a Thinkpad T23, http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:T23 i want to install ubuntu on it and was recomended to try 7.10.

Comment: @tijybba what is dd?

Comment: @Sergei I advice to use 12.04. Linux/Ubuntu does -not- require better hardware for newer releases. 7.* is way too old.

Comment: @Sergei `dd` is used to perform bit-perfect disk copies.

Comment: My mistake if you are not using Ubuntu then `dd` is of no use . Please refer answer for Unetbootin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely go for [Lubuntu 12.04 Latest version](http://lubuntu.net/) as its practical System Specs clearly explained in [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/162632/63025.)

If you **just** want to try Ubuntu 7.10 through Usb Drive from windows then try [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) known to work with Ubuntu 7.10 [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/unetbootin/wiki/builtin-distributions) .