# Which Ubuntu version is suitable for an Intel Pentium 3 Processor?

Tags: system-requirements

My PC has the following specs:

- Intel Pentium 3 Processor
- 256 MB RAM
- 20 GB HardDisk Space

Which Ubuntu version best suits my PC?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 4):

Your best option (and most likely your only option) would be to go with Lubuntu 12.04 or 12.10.  I have it installed on one of my old Pentium 3's with about 160mb of ram and it works fine. Not the quickest but definitely usable on a day to day basis.

Just remember that its not only about the operating system.  The programs you use also has a huge impact on the usability.  Lubuntu comes with fast and light weight programs which makes the system very usable on a day to day basis.  You should even be able to do some multitasking with easy for example listen to music and browsing the Internet.

Comment: from which website i get this Lubuntu 12.04

Comment: http://lubuntu.net/    Download the Intel x86 version

Answer (score 2):

[Definitely Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162626/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-lubuntu).  I'd recommend that you use the [alternate install](http://lubuntu-12.10-alternate-i386.iso) from [this page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/).  The alternate installer does not use the graphical interface, so requires less RAM and will run faster.

Answer (score 0):

After 40 mins trying to boot Ubuntu 11.10 live CD on the P3 (slow CD drive), I was able to boot [Ubuntu 4.10 (Warty Warthog)](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/) **live CD** in minutes.

Side note, possibly of interest: USB boot usually isn’t an option for P3's, since USB boot for PC wasn’t introduced until after 2004 (by that time, P3 boards were being discontinued, for desktop at least).

Comment: Thar's probably why Canonical still keeps old Ubuntu iso images, but if you're installing Warty to give it to your kid to play with it makes more sense to give him a Raspberry Pi and install the Ubuntu Raspberry Pi image on a USB or SD card.