# Does Ubuntu 12.04 LTS runs on my computer? I need help

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm learning on my school about operating system's installation, Ubuntu looks so beauty and fast, even on that old computers.

I have an Emachines L4030, originally with Windows XP Starter Edition, later I upgraded it to Windows XP Professional SP3. Here is my system hardware:

- Procesador Intel Celeron D355 3.33GHz,256 KB L2 de Cache 533 MHz FSB
- Video Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 900 con ranura PC-IExpress Disponible
- HDD 80 GB SATA
- Memory 256 MB DDR2 SDRAM

I want to learn about another kind of systems, I don't want to throw Windows to the trash because I still need it for school, I was thinking on a partition (20GB for XP- 60GB for Ubuntu) but I don't know if Ubuntu will run as I want to with my hardware

I'M SORRY! I forgot to tell you guys that I upgraded the RAM to 1.7GB, I copied the info from internet and I didn't remember the upgrade. Can I use Ubuntu with that upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is the RAM, a little short. You could try anyway to burn a DVD or create a bootable USB with the iso file downloaded from the website and run the live desktop before you install.

Also, you could try other flavours like Xubuntu or Lubuntu which are basically the same as ubuntu but with different desktop interfaces.

Don't forget to download the 32-bit version of the iso you choose, since 64-bit versions are not supported by your CPU (somebody correct me if I'm wrong).

Good luck!

Comment: darent is completely right. Only problem is your RAM. For Ubuntu 12.04 you need at least 512 MB RAM. [see here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts). Rather I will recommend you to install Lubuntu. Which will run much better without giving almost any trouble with 256 MB RAM. [see here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162626/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-lubuntu)

Comment: Since your RAM is 1.7 GB, you are welcomed to Ubuntu. OS will run smoothly in your system.

Comment: Well that's totally different... I used to run Ubuntu 12.04 with 1.5 GB and it ran smooth, even with all compiz effects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 256 MB RAM is quite low for efficient working. But I think Lubuntu (which is based on Ubuntu) will work just fine. So try installing Lubuntu.