# How to replace Windows XP with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, downloads, system-installation, windows-xp

I have found out that they will be phasing out windows XP which I currently use. My brother recommended I switch to Ubuntu.

Firstly, my computer itself is ancient, around 10 years old, will I be able to use Ubuntu?

My other questions include what happens if I download this and it doesn't work? What happens to XP if I do download? Yes, my questions may be simple to some, but I'm just a little unsure of how all this works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! First, download is different than install. Nothing bad will happen if you download, but you may face troubles installing. In your specific case, you should backup all your data (pictures, music, etc.) and then install [*Lubuntu*](http://lubuntu.net/) (it is a lightweight version of Ubuntu). If you have troubles installing it, create a new question telling us all the errors. Good luck!

Comment: as lucio said, lubuntu or xubuntu should work fine if xubuntu didn't, and just google how to duaboot between windows and ubuntu, your xp should stay untouched

Comment: Hi, we would need more information then this, computer make/model as well if you want to keep xp (dual-boot).

Comment: If you still have problems, I can assist you further, give me skype name or somethng...

Comment: before doing anything backup any important data and you can either dual boot or use ubuntu as ur only os; if u have enough disk space u can dual bootin

Answer (score 1):

As to your first question, I would recommend that you install Lubuntu (instead of Ubuntu) on your 10-year old computer. Lubuntu is a variant of Ubuntu which is more lightweight and faster.

Related: [What are the minimum system requirements for Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162626/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-lubuntu)

You can find more information about Lubuntu & download it here: http://lubuntu.net

As to your second question, it is possible to install Lubuntu AND Windows XP on your computer, and you can choose which one to boot each time your restart your computer. (That is provided you have enough available disk space to install both operating systems.) So, nothing happens to your Windows.

But the best thing is, you will also be able to *try* Lubuntu, without installing anything on your computer, before you actually do decide to install it. All you need to do is create a bootable USB drive or CD with Lubuntu, and boot your PC from it. Start from http://lubuntu.net, and if you have any more questions, do not hesitate to post them here.