# Ubuntu for old tablet PC

Tags: distro-recommendation

I want to know which of the light versions of Ubuntu would be the best for said tablet.

Specs are as follow :

```
CPU: 1.2 Ghz
Memory: 1G RAM
Storage: 60G Hard Drive.
```

It has a pen, usb slots VGA capabilites, as well as a mic, speaker and dual sound. I'm looking for the smallest possible distro for the best experience possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a PC with roughly these specs some time ago... the Ubuntu full version does **not** work well on it. At all.

Install [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) - it work run smoothly and without any problems, hopefully ;)

Answer (score 0):

Till a couple of weeks back I was using Lubuntu on a 1.2 ghz dual core , 1 GB ram. 
Refer [What are the minimum system requirements for Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162626/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-lubuntu)