# How to make Lubuntu run smoother on old hardware?

Tags: drivers, updates, lubuntu, .desktop

I've installed Lubuntu today and noticed that the performance of it on my computer even after that distro being so lightweight is a bit heavy on my system. It has all those animations when you open and close or even drag around a window which I would like to disable. Could you guys tell me on how to do that? Even while typing this message, it is so super laggy and the messages and words and delayed.

Also, I'm not sure if my Lubuntu has my graphics driver installed correctly. Is it that which is causing the issue? Please help me out guys. How do I update/install graphic drivers for my card?

My PC specs (it's old, hence why I Went with Lubuntu):

- Intel Pentium 4 2.8GHz
- 1.5 GB RAM
- 80 GB HDD
- 32 MB graphics

Comment: You could try running in low-graphics mode all the time or fiddling around with Unity Tweak Tool.

Comment: @grooveplex But Lubuntu doesn't use Unity, so the Unity Tweak Tool is irrelevant. :)

Comment: I believe your computer meets all [requirements](http://askubuntu.com/a/162632/530811) by flying colours (except for RAM, which is a little odd), so maybe it might be a graphics issue after all...

Comment: Run `$ glxinfo | grep render` to see if it is properly using hardware rendering. It should return "direct rendering: Yes"

Comment: @grooveplex - The ram is actually 1GB + 512MB, so 1.5GB. Got it? Might be a graphic issue, then? But how do I solve it, then? It's like laggy, I feel Win XP was way faster than this. 
Reversiblean - I tried that and it said I had to install some kind of a program. This is my first time using Lubuntu, literally first time coming into Linux/Ubuntu OS. Could you please help me out in that command?

Comment: Any help guys? @grooveplex ?