How many RAM speed ist required for Lubuntu?
I have an old computer (from 15 years ago) who works very slow with "Windows Vista".
My computer has:

2GHZ of CPU speed
800MHZ of FSB speed
4GB of RAM
667MHZ of RAM speed

I installed lubuntu 24.04 to have more speed.
Lubuntu is very slow, I waited 15 seconds to open FireFox.
Why is it so slow ?

This question is similar to: Will my device work with Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/162626/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-lubuntu

You're asking for off-topic opinion given a lack of specifics. On some of my older hardware (esp. on devices with only 4GB of RAM) I have to ensure I provide sufficient swap (refer Lubuntu docs on the discourse) for many tasks, as the performance hit without it is steep; but you've not given any clues as to how you use your system, what apps etc. If you're not matching apps & the LXQt desktop swap may matter more due to choices.. Lubuntu haven't provided system requirements since 2018 as per https://lubuntu.me/taking-a-new-direction/

fyi:  firefox is packaged as a snap for 24.04; as such the confined environment needs to be setup; which makes the initial execution a little slower; but it also provides additional security. If the first run speed really worries you, you could always replace it with a different packaging format (you'll lose security benefits the confined execution provides; but only you can decide what matters to you)...  Loads of people have written about this choice though.

I have an install of Kubuntu on an external SSD for use with newer laptop & backup to desktop. Old 2006 laptop with only 1.5GB of RAM would not install Ubuntu and was slow with falback GUI. Kubuntu installed and was a bit slow. But my external SSD was very functional as long as I did not add too many apps or Windows in Firefox at once. But I uninstall all snaps. Suggest SSD & some optimization. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Still do same optimizations with newer Kubuntu versions.

On that machine you can try: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mx-linux/files/Final/Fluxbox/MX-23.4_fluxbox_x64.iso/download

The computer is simply underpowered for Ubuntu and its flavors. Ubuntu and its flavors are not geared towards very old hardware, you may want to look for a different distribution. However, a web browser (like e.g, but not limited to) Firefox is on "normal" desktop systems the program demanding the most resources, so the browser problem will remain, no matter which Linux distro you are going to use.

@noisefloor the oldest PC I use in QA testing of Ubuntu and flavors is a 2005 HP Compaq; I use a number of boxes that were made between 2005-2009, though to get the most of out of them often requires a little tweaking (swap I mentioned in prior comment being one example; esp. on installs made with calamares installer). No actual CPU specs were provided that can make a difference with firefox starts (OP you mentioned a marketing sales speed that is ~meaningless; FSB matters or the 667 you did give is slow but CPU is a clue too only you didn't provide actual CPU spec)

@guiverc: sure, *buntu works mostly on old machines. However, IMHO there is an important difference between "it works" and "it is usable for regular desktop use".

@noisefloor  I'm on my primary PC currently which is only ~7 years old; but I'm about to change locations where I'll continue on a ~16yo/2008 c2d-q9400 dell, and the main thing I'll notice is the form factor differences (from 5 displays here down to 2 displays!, same keyboard & mouse though).. I'll use it slightly differently, and it is configured differently; but its what I do most days for 2-3 hours and it works for me...   The reduced screen capacity is what I really notice most in my own desktop use.

A computer from 15 years ago, cannot be expected to run a modern graphical operating system well. The fact that it runs at all is already very impressive! There is no magic wand that can make an extremely old (12 years is ancient for a computer, >3 years is already "old") machine run modern software quickly.
That said, while Lubuntu is indeed the lightest (and therefore fastest on old hardware) flavor of Ubuntu, it is still graphical and heavier than things designed to be ultra lightweight. So maybe (maybe) you would get slightly faster results if you try LXLE or another of the options listed in this random article I found.
At the end of the day, however, nothing is going to work perfectly. This is an old machine so you need to accept that it will be slower. Especially if you want to try running modern web browsers like firefox which are huge and require significant resources. You might want to try a lightweight, minimalist web browser instead.
