# What distro of ubuntu to choose when I focus on performance? kubuntu?

Tags: unity, gnome, kubuntu, performance, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lighter in CPU/Memory Usage: Lubuntu or Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112418/lighter-in-cpu-memory-usage-lubuntu-or-xubuntu)

I do have an old laptop. it has 512mb of ram and weak processor. I would like to use it only for internet(www and email). Sometimes maybe run a movie on it.

I have a fresh ubuntu installation, but its very slow :(

how can I force ubuntu to focus on performance first and don't use anything that will slow down my computer.

I now use unity (I think its the default thing),but i'm willing to switch to any other except the terminal.

I use firefox or chrome for www and email.

is kubuntu better for performance than ubuntu?

I think I have good graphic card ( I was ableto connect monitor to it and there set resolution to 1610xsomething)

Comment: @vasa1 - Yes it does, but I need to know if UAdapter is asking also about tweaking Ubuntu to be more faster (Which is an already existing question) or to know which Ubuntu distro to use (Which is the one you are mentioning). Anyway if you flag it as such I will follow.

Comment: @Luis Alvarado, very true. I have flagged it as a duplicate of your link I gave above. But, as you pointed out, OP may just be wanting "to optimize" the present distro and that too has been asked before.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I want to know what distro to use

Comment: @vasa1 I want to know what distro to use

Comment: @UAdapter Then friend, the answer below will guide you to the light ^^.

Comment: lol, you guys are dumb :D

Answer (score 5):

If you have such a low end system (For me 512 MB of RAM is still not low, but it depends also on your Motherboard and CPU) I actually recommend Xfce with Xubuntu or LXDE with Lubuntu. Both are oriented towards low end systems.

I actually have a question regarding this that was very well answered by fossfreedom: [Lighter in CPU/Memory Usage: Lubuntu or Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112418/lighter-in-cpu-memory-usage-lubuntu-or-xubuntu)

Another one would be: [What is the difference between Ubuntu and its derivatives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives)

So you have a lot of alternatives. If you still want to use Gnome, KDE or Unity, the most important hardware you may need is a video card, followed by RAM.

In order of which one is faster and uses less resources (From less resource usage to highest resource)

1. Lubuntu
2. Xubuntu
3. Ubuntu
4. Kubuntu

In some hardware Kubuntu might be a little faster than Ubuntu but never will Ubuntu or Kubuntu be as fast or use as little resources as Lubuntu or Xubuntu. So if you want performance and want to use Firefox or Chrome, go with Xubuntu first.

Comment: is xubuntu better than ubuntu? I think ubuntu is native so it should be faster

Comment: I don't care what .... gui? I use. its a laptop for internet only, so I want to use firefox or chrome (it depends on performance)

Comment: Update answer to show the speed and resource usage.

Comment: thx, its very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

With so little RAM I would install Lubuntu. I'm afraid that even Xubuntu would be too much for your system to perform reasonably well.

This said, you may try both if you have the time to experiment a bit.

Comment: thx, I will read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for ubuntu server with fvwm-crystal or any other window manager, skip the desktop.