# Ubuntu on old pc

Tags: system-installation

I have an old sempron 1.60GHz single cored pc with 1Gb of ram and I want to know what version of Ubuntu should install into it(ubuntu 12.04,12.10,13.04 does not work)

Comment: 12.04 lubuntu might work. But what do you want to use the computer for? gaming just browsing? server? It depends a lot on what distro you should get. I would go with a server for that specification, but then I like servers...

Comment: For normal office tasks and some simple games like pacman or mario bros. I will try it thanks

Answer (score 4):

First I would try out the actual Lubuntu release, which is a lightwight Ubuntu. I installed it on my year 2000 computer (1GHz, 256MB RAM) and it worked.
Download and burn it as usual.

http://lubuntu.net/

I wouldn't recommend to install older Ubuntu-Versions.

Comment: It didn't really have 256KB RAM?! you must mean MB right?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend any of the latest Ubuntu version. Not because they will not work but because they will feel slow on your Budget PC. Your CPU is actually on the low end. I am guessing it has 256KB of Cache. If so then having this to consider and the fact that maybe you have an old integrated video card I would suggest to first try Xubuntu or Lubuntu before going with Ubuntu, Kubuntu or Gnome Ubuntu. They were created for low PC specs and as such should work ideally for you.

Here is a particular case I had: [Lighter in CPU/Memory Usage: Lubuntu or Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112418/lighter-in-cpu-memory-usage-lubuntu-or-xubuntu)

That should give you an insight into which one to choose. Know that I have tested both, Xubuntu and Lubuntu and they use almost the same amount of RAM / Video / CPU, Xubuntu having a theme similar to the old Gnome DE (Menu at the Upper Left Corner) and Lubuntu having one similar to Windows XP (With the menu at the Bottom Left Corner).

This is just taking into consideration on how the Desktop will feel without even loading any apps. We can add afterwards the fact that you may open an Office product, listen to music, play a game, navigate the web and more. This will be tough of the poor Sempron. The old guy has given it's best to make you feel happy all this years.