# Ubuntu 12.04 window jitter

Tags: window

I'm on ubuntu 12.04, running the propriety nvidia drivers (i have tried using the generic drivers). Whenever i drag a window around it slowly redraws itself. Any ideas on what to try?

System Specs

- P4 2.6 GHZ
- 2 Gigs memory
- Geforce 4 Mx 20 video card

Comment: Your system is fairly old. Try running a lighter desktop environment like lubuntu or xubuntu. Read http://askubuntu.com/questions/112418/lighter-in-cpu-memory-usage-lubuntu-or-xubuntu

Answer (score 0):

First, remove all the failed driver installations using:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then install the correct propriatary drivers:

```
 sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Don't forget to reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This caused my system to only show a resolution of 1024 x 764