# Am I better off with xbuntu or lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I have an old computer and I have installed the latest Ubuntu 14.0 LTS 32-bit. However, the computer is fairly slow. Applications take long to open. My hardware specifications are the following:
                - AMD Athlon 64 Processor 3500+
                - 1 GB Ram

This computer runs well on windows XP since I set it back to factory settings. But I wanted to try out Ubuntu. Hence I have dual booted it. But the performance is slow hence I am wondering whether I am better off with Lubuntu or xbuntu. If I do need to change, which one is better based on my current hardware. If there are any other better options please let me know. Also, I would like to be able to do some development work with whatever Linux flavor can work with the given specs if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Any answer to this is going to be opinion based, which doesn't match what we look for here on the site.  What we recommend is to run with Live USBs of each and see which performs better for you.  Personally, I use Lubuntu for low-spec systems, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: Regular Ubuntu actually wants a (relative) lot of ram & cpu power. +1 to try a bunch of different distro's live iso's. Don't limit yourself to just -buntu's, try others like CrunchBang, even Puppy or TinyCore for very very low spec computers

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/112418/lighter-in-cpu-memory-usage-lubuntu-or-xubuntu?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer xfce but lxde uses less ram, if you want something that you can costumize and feel fresh out of the box go with xubuntu, if you prefer something closer to windows xp go with lubuntu, you can try both using live usb, here are some instruction on how to make one [How to create a bootable USB stick 
on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Bro try to clean up free space.
Use bleach-bit tool for that purpose.

This may also be possible because you have a 64 bit processor type system.
and you are using 32 bit OS.

I have experienced the same trouble when i once installed windows of different architecture...

And also google your questions .there are millions of ways to speed up ubuntu.

Hope so this will help you.