# Which Ubuntu version should I install on a Toshiba laptop, Satellite P200 RT1?

Tags: downloads

I have a Toshiba laptop, Satellite P200 RT1 which is running Windows XP.

Should I install install the **Long Term Support** Release of Ubuntu 14.04, or the latest **Standard** Release of Ubuntu 15.04?

Should I install a different flavour of Ubuntu, such as Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, etc, given my modest hardware specifications?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/112418/300458

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](/q/333795) and [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](/q/16366)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your specs I would go with Lubuntu 15.04:

**It is more lightweight that any other Ubuntu flavour...**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu

- it runs great on older computers
- it has UI "similar" to XP

Check this article:

http://hubpages.com/hub/Why-Lubuntu-Is-A-Good-Alternative-To-Replace-Windows-XP

...I didn't want copy everything over, so here is the link

*It might seem as overkill, but buy SSD and replace the HDD, IT WILL make a difference as well. 64 GB would be enough (but even so I would buy 120 GB) if you would store your media as movies etc. elsewhere*

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the latest version 15.04 because it possibly provides better driver support than the alternative which would be the long-term-support (LTS) version 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

According to the minimal system requirements, your system meets the bare minimum needed to use the regular desktop edition with Unity.

### Your Laptop:

- http://www.cnet.com/products/toshiba-satellite-p200-rt1-17-pentium-t2080-vista-home-premium-1-gb-ram-120-gb-hdd/specs/

Note that you have a 32 bit processor. **Do not download any 64 bit release!**

### Minimum Specs:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

> Ubuntu Desktop 11.04 and up uses Unity as the default GUI while the
>   previous releases used GNOME Panel by default. In order to run Unity
>   the system needs a more capable graphics adapter – see more here or
>   below:
>
> - 1000 ΜHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
> - 1024 MiB RAM (system memory)
> - **3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB**
>
> From experience, we all know that it is recommended to have 2048 MiB
>   RAM to properly run a day to day Ubuntu.
>
> A good start should be with minimum 1024 and recommended 2048 MiB RAM.

### Solution:

If your Laptop has 2 Gigabytes of Ram, download the 32 bit version of Ubuntu 14.04:

[image]

[Download Link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=CA&version=14.04.2&architecture=i386)

Otherwise you can try these three options:

### Ubuntu Mate

[image]

[Download Link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/15.04/release/ubuntu-mate-15.04-desktop-i386.iso)

### Lubuntu

[image]

[Download Link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/15.04/release/lubuntu-15.04-desktop-i386.iso)

### Xubuntu

[image]

[Download Link](http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso)