# Is there a simple audio player for Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I have Lubuntu 18.0.4 on a thin client, 1.4ghz, 4gb ram. I would like to use it to play streamed internet radio stations like BBC radio 3 and also to play audio from a usb stick.
Two problems: I am new to Lubuntu and the PC is quite limited in resources.
But is quite fast on boot, so good for me.
Any ideas please
Thanks
diode84

Comment: This link will probably give you many choices.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/99237/lightweight-music-player

Comment: I use Lubuntu 18.04 on a thinkpad t43 (1.5gb ram, single core pentium M) and use regular tools.  For local [LAN or NFS shared] content it's usually `cmus` (a terminal client), but also use firefox to stream youtube etc. I do have other music (GUI) clients and do like `audacious` but have no idea if it streams radio off the web (I don't do that).

Answer (score 0):

There is an audio player with a command-line interface called **cmus** which is very ight weight on resources which also allows streaming of internet radio and is also knows to open `.m3u` and `.pls` streams.

Also, `cmus` looks nice and offers several views, a file browser and many configuration settings. `cmus` is available from the standard Ubuntu repositories. ou can install using the command below

```
sudo apt install cmus
```

If you need help on how to use `cmus`, use the command

```
man cmus
```